# How to make HTML Video Background with Text Overlay responsive

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I can't make my Background Video with overlay & Text responsive.
Decrease Resolution width the text does not scale down, but gets cut off by the overflow hide option i believe.
Does not help if i remove the font size parameter

Also, if i try on Safari the Video does not minimize well or at all
result is, that page is cut off on the right side.

The idea is [www.fc-squad.de](http://www.fc-squad.de) the picture in the middle should be replaced by a video. While the page is not really responsible, its ok with Pictures only.

p.S: probably i messed up alot code, by trial and error paste code, delete if result wasnt good

```css
/* ViDEO Background Section */

.callout {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
min-width=600px:

}

 /* Style of the the video */
#myVideo {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
border: 1px solid slategrey;
border-radius: 5px;
   display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1000;


}

/* some content over the video */
.content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
 text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #272D0B;

}
```

```html
<section class="callout">

<!-- The video -->
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="squad-alpha11.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<!-- some overlay text to describe the video --!>
<div class="content">
  <span style="font-size:36px"><h1>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h1>
<span style="font-size:28px"><h2>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h2>
<span style="font-size:20px"><h3>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h3>
<span style="font-size:18px"><h4>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h4>


<a class="button" href="url-to-topic">Call to Action</a>
</div> 

</section>
```

---

Update:

Great, Text is working much better

small and larger window (Firefox), see here video container small resolution and video container medium resolution

But The Video and the whole DIV Section has issues on Safari/iOS... yes the page is generally not optimized, but it was rendering pictures down alteast

But the video is cut off, not playing auto (you must klick play)and text is below not as overlay. Safari screen

I've read its better to make a static picure for small screens, or is there an easy fix for Safari?

Comment: Might wanna check the [view port units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

Comment: thanks, that does the trick with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is just the text not resizing you may want to try use **vw** instead of **px**, that scales down based on view width.

replace your text spans with:

```
<span style="font-size:4vw"><h1>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h1>
<span style="font-size:3.2vw"><h2>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h2>
<span style="font-size:2.2vw"><h3>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h3>
<span style="font-size:1.7vw"><h4>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h4>
```

let me know cause i didn't understand if also the video itself has issues.

Comment: +1 Great.
Text is working much better

small and larger window (Firefox), see in my update the pictures.

But The Video and the whole DIV Section has issues on Safari/iOS... yes the page is generally not optimized, but it was rendering pictures down alteast

But the video is cut off, not playing auto (you must klick play)a nd text is below not as overlay.

I've read its better to make a static picure for small screens, or is there an easy fix for Safari?

Answer (score 0):

used update for information - for better searchability

[Text scales now on small resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YlAX.jpg) 
[works also on medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2q3h.jpg)

But still issue on Safari
[Safari Cut of Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hv6i.jpg)

Comment: (as a rule is better to post update at the bottom of your original post adding title UPDATE:) Autoplay is turned off by default on Safari, users have to activate it at the right/left of the url filed. I'm looking for the video on Safari thing now cause i had the same exact issue on one of my project and i can't remind of how i solved it.

Comment: Found it, most of the problems i had with the video on Safari were solved by adding  'playsinline': 1 to playerVars, like: playerVars: { 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'playsinline': 1, etc },

Comment: thank you for the trip with update :)
About the playerVars, thats with JavaScript? I havent used JavaScript atm

Comment: yes it's js, but i think can be given inline in the html as well, there must be an equivalent